# Reading tsv file with a filter

Tags: d3.js, scaling, csv

I am trying to plot a simple bar graph from a tsv file and would appreciate some help.

First of all, here is a sample input file:

```
ind  count      
0    1228

1    0

2    238

3    9
```

I need to plot number of records (y-axis) vs. "count" (x-axis).

The user has the option via the HTML page to decide at what "count" value to
suppress the data. For example, suppress all records where `count=0`. Changing the number of records and with that the range of data affects the scales of both axes.

I have no problem getting all the data and setting up the scales for the axes. I do that as the first step right after reading in the data from the file (d3.tsv...).  But how do I do that when I only want to use partial data of the input file? I use

```
d3.max(data, function(d){ return +d.indx}
```

to get the number of records in my input file.

I did play with the `filter()` method a bit but (besides being unsuccessful so far) I still think that the right place to filter data out would be right away - when reading the input file.

Chances are this is so obvious that the answer will make me blush but
my brain has given up. With that, thank you for responding!

And now, here is some of my code:

```
function drawBarGraph( minCountNum){
    d3.tsv("../../data/test.tsv", function( error, data){               //get the number of rows and the largest number of the "total" column for scaling purposes

    //y-axis: use number of lines in input file
    var bar_num = d3.max(data, function(d) {  return +d.indx;} );                   //use plus sign (+) in front of a variable to ensure conversion to a numeric value. 
    //x-axis: use largest value of "total reads" from input file;           
    var data_max = d3.max(data, function(d) {  return +d.total;} );
    //set up canvas size 
    var margin = { top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 40, left: 50},
        width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,                   
        height = 2 * bar_num + 2;                                                   //each bar is 1px high and spaced by 1px; add 2px to the bottom to allow a little space between the xAxis and the first data point

    var bar_height = 1;         //yes, draw the bars 1px high                                                   

    //set up the x and y scales
    var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, data_max])      //define original range with min and max 
                .range([0, width]);         //define what resulting range should be 
    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, bar_num*2])         
                .range([0, height]);        

    //set up the x and y axes 
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale( xScale)
                .orient("bottom")
                //.ticks( 5);               //let d3 decide on the number of ticks used or calculate based on longest x-value 
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale( yScale)
                .orient("left")
                .ticks( 0);                 //no ticks or make them the index or node id's

    var canvas = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)      
                    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)    
                .append("g")                
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");  

    var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
                .attr("class", "tooltip")   //add the CSS tooltip
                .style("opacity", 0);

    canvas.selectAll("rect")                
                .data(data)
                .enter()                    
                //.filter(function(d) { return +d.total > 0; })  //this returns 'undefined'
                    .append("svg:a")
                        .attr("xlink:show", "new")
                            .attr("xlink:href", function(d){return ncbi_url + d.taxon_id;})
                    .append("rect")         
                    .attr("width", function(d) { return xScale(d.total);})  
                    .attr("height", bar_height)     
                    .attr("y", function(d,i){ return i * (bar_height + 1);})  
                    .attr("fill", function(d) { return d.color;})
                    .on("mouseover", function(d){
                        div.transition()
                            .duration(200)
                            .style("opacity", .9);
                        div.html(
                                "Node ID: " + d.id + "<br/>Tot. Reads: " + d.total)
                            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
                    })
                    .on("mouseout", function(d){
                        div.transition()
                            .duration(500)
                            .style("opacity", 0);
                    });

    canvas.append("g")                                              
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                    .call(xAxis);

    canvas.append("text")   //add the x-axis label 
                    .attr("x", (width / 2))
                    .attr("y", height + margin.bottom)          
                    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .text("Total Reads");

    canvas.append("g")                                              
                    .call(yAxis);

    canvas.append("text")   //add the y-axis label 
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                    .attr("y", 0 - margin.left + 20)            
                    .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
                    .attr("dy", "1em")
                    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .text("Node #");

    canvas.append("text")  //add a title
                    .attr("x", (width / 2))
                    .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .style("font-size", "20px")
                    .style("text-decoration", "underline")
                    .text("Node Plot");
})   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the best way to do this would be right after getting the data to make sure that all subsequent operations consider only the subset that you want. You can use the `.filter()` function for this.

```
var threshold = ...;
var newdata = data.filter(function(d) { return +d.total > threshold; });
```

(I've taken `total` as the field to filter on like in the code you've posted).

Comment: Thank you Lars!  For some reason I thought the filter method only works once I used the select/selectAll methods on my dataset.  I only had 10 days or so with D3 so far and figured that my problem is pretty basic.  Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: These are actually two different filter functions -- the one you're talking about is implemented in D3 for selections, the one I've used is a general Javascript thing. Both do essentially the same though.